# Export OpenCms' article to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, export, article, opencms

I have a website uses OpenCms (http://www.opencms.org).
Now, I want to replace it by Wordpress (http://wordpress.org).
How to export article from old site (OpenCms) to new one (Wordpress)?

Sorry for my bad Endlish!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OpenCms has a static export feature which exports all the pages to the filesystem, this could come in handy. You can find it under "Administration View  >  Database Management  >  Start Static Export".